# What program should be used to ask user's password on console, check it and only return exit code?

Tags: linux, authentication

What program *just* asks specified user's password (even if calling user is root) and returns exit code 0 if it is OK and 1 if it fails?

Is there such a simple program (i.e. not "sudo" with edited config) to do the task?

Also I'm looking for program that will log in user (checking its password, writing to auth.log), but not execute any programs (like `login`), simply return the exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the simplest way is to write it using [python-pam](http://atlee.ca/software/pam/) using `/usr/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py` as example. The example reads password, authenticates user using PAM and writes message depending on the result. Can be easily changed to varied exit code.

Comment: Please add a link to the **python-pam** project and to the example if possible, so people will have a better idea about what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You want a utility known as [`pwauth`](http://code.google.com/p/pwauth/). It does exactly what you describe: accepts a username and password, and then returns an exit code based on validity. It's designed to be used with apache's mod_auth_external to hook into system authentication, but should work just fine for what you want.

Comment: Good, but it 1. doesn't allow user to be specified on command line, 2. reads password from terminal insecurely.

Comment: @Vi. this is a low-level thing meant to be called from other programs, feeding the username and password to stdin over a pipe. Running it directly on a terminal is a valid way to test it, but not a normal mode of use. The program which calls `pwauth` is responsible for acquiring the password from the user in a sensible way, and taking care of all the other things that e.g. `login` would normally do.

Comment: 3. No log messages appears when checking it, 4. It fails to check root's password...

Comment: Is there a program like "login", but with exit code instead of executing any commands?

Comment: @Vi.what would be the reason for it? `su user -c true` is close. But I don't understand why you want to do it. Are you going to be providing a service to the user you're authenticating? Or is this for some kind of lazy blackhat dictionary attack?

Comment: `su user -c true` doesn't ask the password when started from root. The idea is to first authenticate user with only it's filehandles accessible (not environtment variables, root directory and other things that can affect authentication process) and only after successfull authentication apply environment variables and other things. This is part of `su` or `sudo` analogue that works without set-uid bit. https://github.com/vi/dive.

Comment: "Or is this for some kind of lazy blackhat dictionary attack?" -> There are better ways for "blackhat dictionary attack"s, and logging is usually avoided in such cases.

Comment: If you think you can write a better `su` than `su` then you should be competent enough to perform authentication in your own C code. Your "punt to an external process" method is lazy. The bad kind of lazy. And the fact that you can't even figure out how to get a password from the user and feed it to `pwauth` is a sign you shouldn't be writing security-sensitive code yet.

Comment: I want it to be 1. simple, 2. secure. Putting everything (including actual authentication code) in C is making it less simple. Using python authentication script in user's environment is not secure. So I limit user's environment to file descriptors only for the authentication and use simple script.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to defeats the purpose of an user session, the user has already typed that password when he logged in to his account so it is rude to ask it again for your task; if you do want your program to be based on logging in then the best approach is to support the key rings, this allows the user itself to choose whether or not to explicitly type a password for your task.

Don't force users to type `correct horse battery staple` again when they just did...

Comment: The user is expected to type other user's password, like in `su`. It is part of non-standard login scheme.

Comment: @Vi That is a **very bad** login scheme. No user should know another user's password. *Ever*. For _any_ reason. This is why `su` is generally phased out, and most distributions push their users towards `sudo`.

Comment: I'm using my own user account (among other specialized per-application accounts), but also know root's password on my computer. I don't like sudo because of it seems to be overly complicated (special config file) and don't 100% understand how it works, it relies on suid bit (which I want to try turning off entirely making all filesystems mounted "nosuid"); I want simpler password to be used in regular account and complex password to be used for root. And I want to keep the whole system simple (i.e. not to care about everything everywhere like in suid-bit programs) yet secure.

Comment: @Vi disabling the setuid bit will break so many programs, including `mount` itself and `passwd`, unless you run them at root every single time. That flag is for mounting untrusted filesystems (flash drives, etc.) into the system, but is crucially depended upon for trusted filesystems/utilities. You will not increase security of a system with what you are doing, and if anything are adding additional layers of untested and potentially exploitable code into your authentication scheme.

Comment: There's not harm in just trying to do it (on my computer). setuid is not the sole way of granting additional permissions (like mounting flash drives) to users. /* BTW for flash drives I sometimes use mountlo... which may rely on setuid fusermount... */. Maybe such setuid-less, yet secure and usable system will inspire somebody to do something good in future....

Comment: @Vi.: You have mentioned `simple` a few times; just follow your distro guide to set up `sudo` and be done with it. Given your attitude to keep things simple anything more complex will only yield a broken system, that's because you are trying to keep the complex things simple and hence don't get enough understanding about the consequences of certain solutions. If you can't get `sudo` to work you could go for `su -` and then detach (CTRL-D) when you are done, either one is simple and secure enough to fit your needs. If expirementation isn't a harm, why obsess over complex non-standard security?

Comment: @Vi Also, users will be unable to change their passwords.

Comment: @Darth, Everything that relies on setuid can be substituted with something that started as root, listens UNIX socket, authenticates and executes user's command. "mount", "passwd", "ping" and so on will connect to the socket and send commands there. It seems to be more simple and controllable way than setuid. Whether will it be good/useful or not the future decides - I'm not going to push my semi-ready thing everywhere I can - just show that there is alternative way.